# error when running xlwings and win32com.client

Tags: python, pywin32, win32com, xlwings

I am habing trouble with xlwings and win32com.client, both xlwings and win32com.client have been working fine up until recently. 
When i try to import xlwings for example.

`import xlwings`

I get an ERROR below:

**_pickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '\x00'**

I get a similar error when i run the code below:
`import win32com.client`, 
but get no error when i run 
`import win32com`

i have tried uninstalling python and reinstalling it again but the issue still persist and reloading the modules.

Comment: What version of python, xlwings and pywin32 are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve the issue by just uninstalling python and re-installing it again. Then re-installing xlwings. note that i am using python 3.7.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue uninstalling xlwings, erasing the content of this folder

C:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME\AppData\Local\Temp\gen_py\3.8

and then reinstalling xlwings.

(Anaconda 3 Python 3.8).